# A problem on the convergence of set Lebesgue measures

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Recently,I met a problem while reading Literature [https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00496#:~:text=We%20establish%20continuity%20mapping%20properties%20of%20the%20non-centered,for%20if%20is%20radial%20and%20for%20for%20general.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00496#:%7E:text=We%20establish%20continuity%20mapping%20properties%20of%20the%20non-centered,for%20if%20is%20radial%20and%20for%20for%20general.),
where the article seemed to provide an incorrect proof, and I tried to solve it on my own but ran into a bottleneck. The following description of the problem is my distilled version of the proof process from the article, which can be found in page 17325, the last step of the proof of Lemma 2.3 in the article, thank you!

**Condition**: Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\{f_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be such that $\|f_k-f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}\to0$ as  $k\to\infty$, define the sets $X_k=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:f_k>0\},Y=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:f<0\}.$

**Question**: Does $|X_k\cap Y|\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: You need to show some work.

Answer (score 2):

No.  In any dimension, let $f$ be any everywhere-negative $L^1$ function, and for each $k$ define
$$
f_k(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \|x\|\leq k\\
-f(x) & \|x\|> k
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\|f_k-f\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^d)}\to 0$, but $Y=\mathbb R^d$, so $$|X_k\cap Y|=|X_k|=|\{x\in\mathbb R^d\mid\|x\|>k\}|=\infty$$ for all $k$.

#### Remark

One ***can*** prove the following weaker statement, namely, that given the condition, we have $$\int_{X_k\cap Y}g\to 0$$ for any $g\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$, and that is enough to fix the proof in the linked paper, using $g=2|\nabla f|$.

To prove this, for each $\delta>0$ let $Y_\delta=\{x\in\mathbb R^d\mid f(x)<-\delta\}$.  Fix $\epsilon>0$, and choose $\delta>0$ such that $$\int_{Y\backslash Y_{\delta}} |g|\leq\epsilon\text{.}$$
(Such a $\delta$ exists by the dominated convergence theorem, as the functions $|g|\chi_{Y\backslash Y\delta}$ converge pointwise to $0$ with $\delta$, and are dominated by $|g|$, so we may choose a sequence $\delta_i\to 0$ for which the integrals converge.)

Now we observe that
$$|X_k\cap Y_\delta|\leq \frac{\|f_k-f\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^d)}}{\delta}\to 0\text{,}$$
so that for each $M\in\mathbb N$,
$$\overline{\lim_{k\to\infty}}\int_{X_k\cap Y_\delta}|g|\leq 
\lim_{k\to\infty}M|X_k\cap Y_\delta|+\int_{\{x\in\mathbb R^d\mid g(x)>M\}}|g|
=\int_{\{x\in\mathbb R^d\mid g(x)>M\}}|g|\text{,}$$
but as $M\to\infty$ the right hand side converges to $0$ (applying the dominated convergence theorem to $|g|\chi_{\{x\in\mathbb R^d\mid g(x)>M\}}$),
so that $$\int_{X_k\cap Y_\delta}|g|\to 0\text{.}$$

We then have
$$\overline{\lim_{k\to\infty}}\int_{X_k\cap Y}|g|\leq \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{X_k\cap Y_\delta}|g|
+\int_{Y\backslash Y_\delta}|g|\leq \epsilon\text{.}$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary this completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your replying! There's a real problem with this conclusion, and I need to go through the paper to prove if there are certain details I've overlooked.

Comment: @zyy  Just did an update, it seems their proof has a relatively painless fix.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying again! Sorry I don't quite understand about the first step of integrating over Y\Y_{\delta}, is the integrability of g or the absolute continuity of the integral to be used here? Or some less obvious derivation process is needed?

Comment: @zyy  I was indeed using integrability of $g$ via dominated convergence, in more than one place actually - I've clarified the answer to make this more explicit.  Let me know if that clears things up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient response, I have understood the amended proof you provided!